# javascript display all value of a json

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Json as a string:

```
{"Fromage":
    {
      "Bleu":"4€",
      "Roquefort":"12€"
     },
  "Pain":
    {
      "Baguette":"1€"
    },
  "Yaourt":
    {
      "Faisselle":"2€"
    },
  "biere":"4€"
}
```

Using Javascript, how do I dispaly the name of all elements ?
My expected output is :

```
Fromage
Bleu
Roquefort

Pain
Baguette

Yaourt
Faisselle

biere
```

I tried this

```
const jsonStr = `
{"Fromage":
    {
      "Bleu":"4€",
      "Roquefort":"12€"
     },
  "Pain":
    {
      "Baguette":"1€"
    },
  "Yaourt":
    {
      "Faisselle":"2€"
    },
  "biere":"4€"
}
`;
const value = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(value).length; i++){
       var key = Object.keys(value)[i];
       console.log(key);
       for(var j = 0; j < Object.keys(value.key).length; j++){
          var key2 = Object.keys(value.key)[j];
          console.log(key2);
       }
       console.log("");
}
```

but it returns only first values and then undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Object.keys to get keys of direct children of that object.
Then call function recursively until you see a param obj doesn't have any child object.

Please run/check the following code.

```js
const jsonStr = `
{"Fromage":
    {
      "Bleu":"4€",
      "Roquefort":"12€"
     },
  "Pain":
    {
      "Baguette":"1€"
    },
  "Yaourt":
    {
      "Faisselle":"2€"
    },
  "biere":"4€"
}
`;
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

const showKeys = (obj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      showKeys(obj[key]);
      console.log('');
    }
  });
};

showKeys(jsonObj);
```